# Deserializing SOAP response into generated classes C#

Tags: java, c#, web-services, soap, deserialization

We are integrating with a third party and are having trouble deserializing the response we get from a request. From fiddler, I can see the response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>
  <ns2:updateItemsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ThirdParty/dmn/items/1.1">
     <fileId>bd6e7d83-8bfu-4573-fe32-c67c04355dd0</fileId>
     <fileName>12345.MBG_Items.002.2016-10-26-16-23-35.xml</fileName>
  </ns2:updateItemsResponse>
```

But we cannot deserialize it properly into an updateItemsResponse object. The object is created but the fileId and fileName are both null.
We generated the classes for this request and response and below is the class that was generated:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "updateItemsResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://ThirdParty/dmn/items/1.1", IsWrapped = true)]
public partial class updateItemsResponse
{
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://ThirdParty/dmn/items/1.1", Order = 0)]
    public string fileName;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://ThirdParty/dmn/items/1.1", Order = 1)]
    public string fileId;

    public updateItemsResponse()
    {
    }

    public updateItemsResponse(string fileId, string fileName)
    {
        this.fileId= fileId;
        this.fileName= fileName;
    }
}
```

We know the web service was written in Java, and we had some issues generating the class files - the wsdl we were provided needed some jiggery pokery before we were able to create the class files using svcutil.exe. So I think there is just some tweak I need to make in the generated file.

I've done some searching around this and I am guessing the issue here is the namespaces but I cannot get this to work. I've tried changing the namespace, removing the namespace, changing the order for fileId and fileName - but none of these have made any difference.

Anyone able to see anything obvious I might be missing? It's driving me crazy!!!

EDIT: Have tried this changing the fileId and fileName to XmlElement too but still getting null responses.

Comment: Do fileId and fileName need the Namespace qualification attribute? They don't seem to use a namespace in the fiddler output

Comment: I've already tried removing the namespace attribute. But no joy!

Comment: Try adding this attribute instead:
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]

Comment: Thanks @IanofOz, tried that just now but still no joy.

Comment: Sorry, don't think I can add anything more...

Comment: Thanks @IanofOz, we were on the right track - attributes did need to change - see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Eureka!!!

So it was the attributes that were wrong - on fileId and fileName. Just needed to change them to

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name = "fileId", Namespace = "", Order = 0)]
    public string fileId;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name = "fileName", Namespace = "", Order = 1)]
    public string fileName;
```

and I can now deserialize the response.